# Insert URL column in a HTML table using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

I am creating a Logic App on Azure and in this process I have to create a HTML table with some data, insert that table in an email body and send that email using SendGrid.

Almost everything works, except that my table should have a column containing a URL to some website.

The problem is that somehow the [Create HTML table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-html-table-action) action does not return `<a>` as HTML tag but `&lt;a&gt;` and the [Send email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v4))'s body (even if it's considered HTML content) can't process/interpret that.

I am using a `concat(string1, string2 .. )` `Expression` to build the URL and I think it builds it correctly. The output look ok, only raw output is messed up.

`Create HTML table` action returns this:

Output:

[image: The raw output can be interpreted here]

Raw Output:

```
<td>&lt;a=&quot;https: ...
```

This is how the Output is injected into the email body of `Send Email`:

[image: The raw output will be added]

If the raw output could be changed to be in a more HTML format, the email body will parse it and display the URL in a correct way. *(I'm not sure if I expressed myself very well. But even if I create a simple html file with that raw output, the `a` tag will be displayed in browser as simple text...)*

Any ideas? I think that if I replace the `concat()` expression and generate the URL before, the raw output of `Generate URL table` will still mess up the final result.

Maybe if there is a way to stop the replacement of `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` it will work, but I don't know how to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I initialize a variable to simulate your situation and we can just replace the `&lt;` with `<` and replace the `&gt;` with `>`. Then the send email action will work fine. Please refer to the steps below:
[image]

The whole expression is:

```
replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_table'), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>')
```

Hope it helps~